# How to find all the json files hosted in a domain?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

There is one domain that has lot of json files saved with the following structure:

```
https://example.com/apps/109816311/109816311_meta.json
https://example.com/apps/10823211/10823211_meta.json
https://example.com/apps/1058124/1058124_meta.json
```

The only thing that changes from one url to another is the numbers, but the first numbers before the
slash are always the same ones than the numbers after the slash.

I got some examples of valid urls so I can access those json files, but I'd like to get all of them.

I think there might be around 1500 valid urls , but obviously I can't try every single combination to find out. Is there any way faster to do it?

PS: I tried entering https://example.com/apps/109816311/109816311_meta.json or https://example.com/apps/ at https://pentest-tools.com but it didn't bring any results

Comment: Have you tried `wget` to retrieve only `json` files?

Comment: @DavidPostill with wget I can download the urls I know, but how can I download the other thousand of urls at https://example.com/apps/ which I don't know but actually exist?

Comment: Unless there's some kind of links or directory of those files somewhere, there's no faster way. Which very well may be the reason they chose this scheme. If this was my site, if you'd start enumerating all of those, I'd consider this an attack, and I'd block you.

Comment: @dirkt you are right. I think they actually don't know those json are accessible for the whole world (provided the know the urls of those files of course)